# How to create WebService that returns data in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

hello i want to ask how can i make webservice return JSON in Visual Studio (ASP.NET) without XML tags ?

```
   <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"account":[{"name":"XXXX ","phoneNumber":"5555544 ","email":"sas@sa.com"},{"name":"slh ","phoneNumber":"0565555","email":"1 "}]}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use webapi restful?

Comment: Any MVC controller (or webAPIController) can do that for you

Comment: Web api working with json format.

Comment: thank you but idon't have any idea about API

Answer (score 0):

For WCF REST Service (.svc) to return JSON you need to add attributes on the contract telling it to return JSON. Note that in the below example the response format is set as JSON.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getEmployee/{id}")]
    Employee GetEmployee(int id);
}
```